# Spark hdfs won't find my file

Tags: scala, hadoop, apache-spark

I'm new to scala/spark/hadoop and I've been struggling for 5 hours to only run the example on the [spark doc](http://spark.apache.org/docs/1.2.0/quick-start.html#self-contained-applications) and it seems that it can't find my file:

```
[error] (run-main-0) org.apache.hadoop.mapred.InvalidInputException: Input path does not exist: file:/home/coudra_c/.bashrc
```

Here's the code that produces the error:

```
import org.apache.spark.SparkContext
import org.apache.spark.SparkContext._
import org.apache.spark.SparkConf

object FinalProject {
  def main(args: Array[String]) {
    val logFile = "hdfs://localhost:9000/home/coudra_c/.bashrc" // Should be some file on y\
our system                                                                                  
    val conf = new SparkConf().setAppName("Simple Application").setMaster("local[2]").set("\
spark.executor.memory","1g")
    val sc = new SparkContext(conf)
    val logData = sc.textFile(logFile, 2).cache()
    val numAs = logData.filter(line => line.contains("a")).count()
    val numBs = logData.filter(line => line.contains("b")).count()
    println("Lines with a: %s, Lines with b: %s".format(numAs, numBs))
  }
}
```

But when I run spark-shell and execute the following line:

```
val data = sc.textFile("hdfs://localhost:9000/home/coudra_c/.bashrc", 2).cache()
```

I get no error.

I used sbt as in the example, and the configs are:

```
 scalaVersion := "2.11.7",
 version      := "0.1.0-SNAPSHOT"
 name := "Final Project",
 libraryDependencies += "org.apache.spark" %% "spark-core" % "1.6.3"
```

Please ask if I forgot to tell anything important, thank you for any help.

EDIT:

Here's the hdfs ls command result.
    coudra_c@PC-Colin:~/Documents/spt$ hdfs dfs -ls /home/coudra_c/.bashrc
    -rw-rw-rw-   1 coudra_c supergroup       4287 2017-01-05 21:31 /home/coudra_c/.bashrc

And notice that since I didn't know about the lazy binding, it doesn't work in both spark shell and as a .jar.

And the comments suggests that core-site.xml wasn't found, but the file is not found even if I look at "file://home/coudra_c/.bashrc" or even "/home/coudra_c/.bashrc".

Comment: Can you do `hadoop fs - ls hdfs://localhost:9000/home/coudra_c/.bashrc` on your local system?  is HDFS properly configured?

Comment: I get the description of my /home/coudra_c/.bashrc file I uploaded on hdfs. And since it works on spark-shell I made the assumption my hdfs is properly configurated (this was another struggle...)

Comment: Did you try the `hdfs` command? Does it work? Also, when running in local mode, hdfs is not required. You could do `val data = sc.textFile("/local-dir/logs/foo.txt")`

Comment: Yes, I ran the command and it worked. And I still got "Input path does not exist: file:/home/coudra_c/.bashrc" if I just do sc.textFile("/home/coudra_c/.bashrc")...

Comment: @Krapow - can you share command that you used for uploading this file to `hdfs`... I believe `hdfs` user path starts with `/user/username` (if any) not `/home/username` ; also post command `spark-submit` command you have used to run this job...

Comment: and is the file in `/home/coudra_c/.bashrc` ?  `textFile(localFile)` should work without issues.

Comment: BTW - if you just executed `sc.textFile(...).cache()` in spark shell and got no error - it doesn't prove anything, Spark is lazy and you performed no actions on the loaded file. Try running the whole thing or add some simple action, e.g. `sc.textFile(...).cache().count()`. If you already did that and got no errors, well - ignore this comment :)

Comment: Tzach Zohar you are right, I get an error.
BigDataLearner: I just launched sbt and hit "run" in the prompter.
But I created a /home/coudra_c directory and uploaded my .bashrc so the file would have the same absolute path both in local and in hdfs

Comment: Try replacing localhost with you system Ip address or `127.0.0.1`

Comment: It still doesn't work, and when I copy paste the "non existing" path to a hdfs dfs -ls, it does exist.

Comment: `hadoop fs -ls /` what output of this command?

Comment: *"But when I run spark-shell..."* -- that seems to imply that you get the error when running `spark-submit` on a JAR, but pasting the same exact code in `spark-shell` works perfectly. Is that correct? And more generally, **what is the exact command line that produces the error**?

Comment: The error message shows that the Hadoop client libraries resolve `hdfs://localhost:9000` as `file:`. Which probably means that **the `core-site.xml` configuration file was not found in the CLASSPATH** and the lib reverted silently to the hard-coded default i.e. "use local filesystem because it's just a unit test, no HDFS service is present".

Comment: Please see the edit I made